# Powershell machine names in my remote registry finder is not outputting to text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy machines names to a text file if the programs are found in the user installations

machines are copying over to text file however it is getting machines that are not installed as well

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\temp\MY_TEST.txt | ForEach-Object {$_.trim()}
foreach($computer in $computers) {

Invoke-command -computername $computer {

$UserHives = Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^HKEY_USERS\\S-1-5-[\d\-]+$'}

foreach($Hive in $UserHives)
{
# Construct path from base key
$Path = Join-Path $Hive.PSPath "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

# Attempt to retrieve Item property
$one = Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.displayname -eq 'ABC'}
$two = Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.displayname -eq 'DEF'}
$three = Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.displayname -eq '123'}

if($one -or $two -or $three){

        $computer | Out-File C:\temp\MY.txt -Append
        }


} #end foreach

}
#only copies here outside of loop    
#$computer | Out-File C:\temp\MY.txt -Append

} #end main foreach loop
```

I expect only machines found in my registry hive to be copied to text file

Comment: you are depending on `$one`, `$two`, & `$three` being blank if no item is found. however, you do not initialize those $Vars ... so if they are ever set to non-blank ... they will always be non-blank. you really otta initialize those three EVERY time thru the loop. something like `$one = $two = $three = $Null` seems likely to do the job. [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.  Do I put it after the first foreach loop.  $one = $two = $three = $Null.  How do I put it for every foreach loop.  Thanks.

Comment: add it immediately before the 3 lines that those $vars are assigned to. just after this >>> `# Attempt to retrieve Item property` <<<

Comment: $One = $two = $three = $null  I put this in the main foreach loop.  But still not working

Comment: it MUST be in the loop where the $vars are being assigned values. [*grin*] that is NOT the main foreach ... it is in this one >>> `foreach($Hive in $UserHives)` <<<

Comment: Yup, that's what I did  foreach($Hive in $UserHives) {$one = $two = $three = $null  }.  It's not working.  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196670/discussion-between-masoman-and-lee-dailey).

Comment: ah! then you likely need to start working your way thru your code - step by step - to see where the problem is. i can't replicate your situation since i only have on system. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: i don't have any other ideas. sorry! [*blush*]